# What http status to return if a service is missing in order to return data

Tags: http-status-codes

I have a REST service 'A' that relies on an external service 'B' to perform a task.

If 'B' is not available at the time 'A' needs it to fulfill a request, what status should I return?

Is a 503 appropriate in this case? In a way we could say that service 'A' is not available since it can't perform all the work, however in reality only the dependent service is not available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the API consumer perspective, it won't mater whether *your server* or *the upstream server that you are proxying* is unavailable. You could return either [`500`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.6.1) or [`503`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.6.4):

> [**6.6.1.  500 Internal Server Error**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.6.1)
>
> The `500` (Internal Server Error) status code indicates that the server
> encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling
> the request.

> [**6.6.4.  503 Service Unavailable**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.6.4)
>
> The `503` (Service Unavailable) status code indicates that the server
> is currently unable to handle the request due to a temporary overload
> or scheduled maintenance, which will likely be alleviated after some
> delay.  The server MAY send a `Retry-After` header field
> to suggest an appropriate amount of time for the
> client to wait before retrying the request. [...]

If the operation is read-only, for example, you may want to return some cached/default data to avoid the error.